# embedLink in Google drive's file resource

Tags: google-drive-api

When I get a file's metadata using Google drive REST API, there is no field like `embedLink` in file's resource. While in documentation of file resource it is mentioned that this field is meant for embeddable link. How do I get this field in my file's resource?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Only files with known mime types contain an `embedLink` such as Docs files and files that can be previewed with Drive's Preview app.